# Is PHP's "alternative syntax" allowing this or is it the switch statement?

Tags: php, syntax, switch-statement

I wrote a switch statement in PHP a few days ago and it was executing multiple conditions at a time. I couldn't figure what went wrong until I noticed I accidentally wrote `default;` instead of `break;` after one of the conditions.

Once the switch statement found a matching case, it executed the code inside as well as the code inside all of the cases that followed it.

```
$number = 3;

switch($number){
    case 1:
        echo 'One';
    default; // who needs break
    case 2:
        echo 'Two';
    default;
    case 3:
        echo 'Three';
    default;
    case 4:
        echo 'Four';
    default;
    case 5:
        echo 'Five';
    default;
    default:
        echo 'Other';
}
```

This returns `ThreeFourFiveOther` (http://codepad.org/37zvAPiW).

Keep in mind, **PHP never returned an error for this**. Does the logic of switch statements permit my code above or is it PHP's "[alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)"?

Comment: The php swtich satement is build that if it enters a case it only exits if a `break;` follows otherwise it's going until the end! Means if you change the `default;` in case 4 it would end there and the output would be: `ThreeFour`. Does that makes sense to you?

Comment: It's nothing to do with alternative syntax; just a logic error.... and I believe that there was an RFC that only one default would be permitted in a switch, and that it must be the last entry in the switch chain, though I can't recall if it was accepted

Comment: what is the purpose of `default;` in every case? What you trying to do?

Comment: @Rizier123 it's not just `the php switch`. this is how `switch` works in any language, which lets you do some sort of (limited) cascading when needed within `switch`.

Answer (score 3):

It works because PHP allows semicolon `;` to be used the same way `:` in `switch` syntax, i.e.

```
switch($a) {
   case 1;     // semicolon
      // foo
   break;
}
```

is the same as

```
switch($a) {
   case 1:
      // foo
   break;
}
```

therefore from the above perspective you just planted `default` very early and having no `break` caused snowball effect.

Comment: It's monday, but i think you meant. `snowball` effect ?

Answer (score 0):

`Default` in each case is just normal command, and have nothing to do with `default` in 'else' branch.

When the `case` isn't terminated/break with `break` command, another cases are executed too. In this case it's the same as if you remove `default` commands from `case`s, because these `default`s do nothing.

```
switch($number){
    case 1:
        echo 'One';
    case 2:
        echo 'Two';
    case 3:
        echo 'Three';
    case 4:
        echo 'Four';
    case 5:
        echo 'Five';
    default:
        echo 'Other';
}
```

Comment: @tryth your test makes no sense. default cannot exist on its own. it's part of `switch`

Answer (score -1):

It works if you do use break statements: http://codepad.org/mFjlaVxz